# Syntax Error on token that says it should be deleted

Tags: java, syntax-error

my source code is:

```
System.out.print("Enter an Alphabet: ");
char ch = scan.next().charAt(0);

switch (ch) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        System.out.println(+ch " is a vowel.");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println(+ch " is a consonant.");
}
```

but it says that it has a syntax error on "is a vowel" and on "is a consonant". can someone tell me what's wrong in my code?

Comment: You are building the String incorrectly. Syntax should be `ch + " is a vowel."`. The `+` concatenates the char with the following string you defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` is on the wrong side of your variable I think.

```
System.out.println(ch + " is a vowel.");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an Alphabet: ");
    char ch = scan.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.format("'%s' is a %s.", ch, isVowel(ch) ? "vowel" : "consonant");
}

public static boolean isVowel(char ch) {
    ch = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
    return ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u';
}
```